# Optimizar código en PHP para calcular diferencia de timestamps

Tags: php, date, optimización, timestamp

Estoy realizando un ejercicio para trabajar con la función diff de PHP, en el que dado un arreglo tengo que calcular la diferencia de minutos entre los elementos del arreglo, si la diferencia de minutos es menor a 2 y la diferencia de horas es 0 eliminar estos elementos del arreglo.

Ejemplo:

Dado el arreglo

```
$a = [
    0 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:00"],
    1 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:20"],
    2 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:25"],
    3 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:00"],
    4 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:10"],
    5 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:01:20"],
    6 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:10"],
    7 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:30"],
    8 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:56:30"],
    9 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:00"],
    10 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:30"],
    11 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:40"],
    12 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:50"],
    13 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:05:50"]
 ];
```

Se tiene que comparar `$a[0][1]` y `$a[1][1]` para calcular la diferencia de minutos y horas, luego `$a[1][1]` y `$a[2][1]` y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al ultimo elemento del arreglo. Si por ejemplo entre `$a[0][1]` y `$a[1][1]` la diferencia es menor a 2 minutos y la diferencia de horas es 0, se debe eliminar el elemento `$a[1]`. de tal manera que al final el arreglo quede con los elementos que tienen mas de 2 minutos de diferencia y mas de 1 hora de diferencia.

El siguiente código que desarrolle funciona correctamente, sin embargo **quisiera saber si existe una mejor forma de hacerlo, o mejorarlo.**

```
$a = [
    0 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:00"],
    1 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:20"],
    2 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:25"],
    3 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:00"],
    4 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:10"],
    5 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:01:20"],
    6 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:10"],
    7 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:30"],
    8 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:56:30"],
    9 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:00"],
    10 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:30"],
    11 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:40"],
    12 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:50"],
    13 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:05:50"]
 ];

$t = count($a)-1;

foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if($key < $t){
        $date1 = new DateTime($a[$key][1]);
        $date2 = new DateTime($a[$key+1][1]);
        $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
        $m = $interval->i;
        $h = $interval->h;
        if($m < 2 && $h == 0){
            $aux[] = $key+1;
        }
    }
}

foreach($aux as $key => $value){
    unset($a[$value]);
}

print_r($a);
```

El codigo anterior imprime:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [1] => 2017-10-2 08:00:00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [1] => 2017-10-2 12:01:20
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [1] => 2017-10-2 13:56:30
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [1] => 2017-10-2 18:04:40
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Una posible alternativa: convertir a tiempo UNIX, y trabajar sobre la diferencia.

Una vez en tiempo UNIX, si la diferencia es menor a `120` (2 minutos), **por fuerza** ha de ser menor a 1 hora :-)

```
$a = [
    0 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:00"],
    1 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:20"],
    2 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:00:25"],
    3 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:00"],
    4 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 08:01:10"],
    5 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:01:20"],
    6 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:10"],
    7 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 12:02:30"],
    8 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:56:30"],
    9 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:00"],
    10 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 13:57:30"],
    11 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:40"],
    12 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:04:50"],
    13 => [0 => 310, 1=>"2017-10-2 18:05:50"]
 ];

$t = count($a)-1;

foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if($key < $t){
        $date1 = ( new DateTime($a[$key][1]) )->getTimestamp( );
        $date2 = ( new DateTime($a[$key+1][1]) )->getTimestamp( );
        $interval = $date2 - $date1;
        if( $interval < 120 ) {
            $aux[] = $key+1;
        }
    }
}

foreach($aux as $key => $value){
    unset($a[$value]);
}

print_r($a);
```

Lo anterior genera

> Array (
>    [0] => Array ( [0] => 310 [1] => 2017-10-2 08:00:00 )
>    [5] => Array ( [0] => 310 [1] => 2017-10-2 12:01:20 )
>    [8] => Array ( [0] => 310 [1] => 2017-10-2 13:56:30 )
>    [11] => Array ( [0] => 310 [1] => 2017-10-2 18:04:40 )
>   )

Que es la misma salida que tu esperas, pero con menos operaciones.

> DateTime.getTimestamp( )

Nos devuelve un entero conteniendo la fecha UNIX contenida en el `DateTime`, que, recordemos, es el número de segundos transcurridos desde  el 1 de enero de 1970.

Esta aproximación puede presentar *inconvenientes* si las zonas horarias de los `DateTime` **no son la misma**; circunstancia que no se da en tu caso.

Comment: Genial, también es una buena alternativa. +1

Comment: Me parece un acercamiento más correcto que el que plantea el usuario, ya que comparando únicamente los elementos `i` y `h` del objeto `DateDiff` no descartarás aquellos cuyo i < 2 y h = 0, pero donde los días, meses o años sean mayores que 0. Usando la diferencia en segudos de fechas unix, la comparación es más sencilla y de acuerdo a lo que se pide.